# HTML interface for a Autonomus car on ESP32

Tags: html, esp32

I am trying to build a Web interface for my autonomous GPS car project. I want to input the coordinates and also assign two other buttons which, when pressed will perform two different functions, I tried different solutions from net but can't mix inputting the coordinates and the buttons. The code for getting coordinates is given below, Please suggest changes so that I can have two more buttons with specific functions.

```
#include <Arduino.h>
  #include <WiFi.h>
  #include <AsyncTCP.h>
#include <ESPAsyncWebServer.h>
double lati1;
double logi1;
double lati2;
double logi2;
AsyncWebServer server(80);

// REPLACE WITH YOUR NETWORK CREDENTIALS
const char* ssid = "******";
const char* password = "*******";

const char* PARAM_INPUT_1 = "input1";
const char* PARAM_INPUT_2 = "input2";
const char* PARAM_INPUT_3 = "input3";
const char* PARAM_INPUT_4 = "input4";


// HTML web page to handle 3 input fields (input1, input2, input3)
const char index_html[] PROGMEM = R"rawliteral(
<!DOCTYPE HTML><html><head>
  <h2>Autonomus GPS Robot Car<h2>
  <h3> Submit your Destination coordinates</h3>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  </head><body>
  <form action="/get">
    <br> 
    Waypoint 1 Latitude : <input type="text" name="input1">
     <br>
   <br>
    Waypoint 1 Longitude: <input type="text" name="input2">
  <br><br>
    <br> 
    Waypoint 2 Latitude : <input type="text" name="input3">
     <br>
   <br>
    Waypoint 2 Longitude: <input type="text" name="input4">
  <br><br>
   <input type="submit" value="Submit">

        </form>

</body></html>)rawliteral";

void notFound(AsyncWebServerRequest *request) {
  request->send(404, "text/plain", "Not found");
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  if (WiFi.waitForConnectResult() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.println("WiFi Failed!");
    return;
  }
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("IP Address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

  // Send web page with input fields to client
  server.on("/", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request){
    request->send_P(200, "text/html", index_html);
  });

  // Send a GET request to <ESP_IP>/get?input1=<inputMessage>
  server.on("/get", HTTP_GET, [] (AsyncWebServerRequest *request) {
    String latitude1;
    String latitude1Param;
    String longitude1;
    String longitude1Param;
    String latitude2;
    String latitude2Param;
    String longitude2;
    String longitude2Param;
    if (request->hasParam(PARAM_INPUT_2)||request->hasParam(PARAM_INPUT_1) ) {
    // GET input1 value on <ESP_IP>/get?input1=<latitude>

      latitude1 = request->getParam(PARAM_INPUT_1)->value();
      latitude1Param = PARAM_INPUT_1;

    // GET input2 value on <ESP_IP>/get?input2=<longitude>

       longitude1 = request->getParam(PARAM_INPUT_2)->value();
       longitude1Param = PARAM_INPUT_2;

// GET input3 value on <ESP_IP>/get?input3=<latitude>

      latitude2 = request->getParam(PARAM_INPUT_3)->value();
      latitude2Param = PARAM_INPUT_3;

    // GET input4 value on <ESP_IP>/get?input4=<longitude>

       longitude2 = request->getParam(PARAM_INPUT_4)->value();
       longitude2Param = PARAM_INPUT_4;
  }
    else {
      latitude1 = "No message sent";
      latitude1Param = "none";
      longitude1 = "No message sent";
      longitude1Param = "none";
      latitude2 = "No message sent";
      latitude2Param = "none";
      longitude2 = "No message sent";
      longitude2Param = "none";

    }
    Serial.println(latitude1);
    Serial.println(longitude1);
    Serial.println(latitude2);
    Serial.println(longitude2);
    lati1=(latitude1.toFloat());
    logi1=(longitude1.toFloat());
    lati2=(latitude2.toFloat());
    logi2=(longitude2.toFloat());
    //Serial.println(lati,6);
    //Serial.println(logi,6);
    request->send(200, "text/html", "Coordinates sent to the robot with Waypoint 1 latitude: " + latitude1 +
                                     "   longitude: " + longitude1 + "<br>" "Waypoint 2 latitude: " + latitude2 +
                                     "   longitude: " + longitude2 +"<br><a href=\"/\">Return to Home Page</a>");
  });
  server.onNotFound(notFound);
  server.begin();
}

void loop() {

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### APPROCH 1

change the html to this

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
   <head>
      <h2>Autonomus GPS Robot Car<h2>
      <h3> Submit your Destination coordinates</h3>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   </head>
   <body>
      <form action="/get">
        <br> 
        Waypoint 1 Latitude : <input type="text" name="input1">
         <br>
       <br>
        Waypoint 1 Longitude: <input type="text" name="input2">
      <br><br>
        <br> 
        Waypoint 2 Latitude : <input type="text" name="input3">
         <br>
       <br>
        Waypoint 2 Longitude: <input type="text" name="input4">
      <br><br>
       <input type="submit" value="submit" name="commit">
       <input type="submit" value="go" name="commit">
       <input type="submit" value="stop" name="commit">
       </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

now depending on which button in the form is clicked the param **commit** will change

so simply read it

```c
commitParam = request->getParam("commit")->value();
```

and do the logic according to its value

```c
      if(commitParam == "go"){
        Serial.println("GO");
      } else if (commitParam == "stop"){
        Serial.println("STOP");
      } else {
        Serial.println("NOTHING");
      }
```

This will submit the form but depending on which button you pushed, you can distingish by reading the commit param.

this is one way or you can try making two diffrent routes for both the buttons and redirecting the page when the button are clicked and you can execute your logic on the button's **GET** method

### APPROCH 2

make both the buttons as links ( you can add some css to make it look like a botton if you want )

```html
<head>
      <h2>Autonomus GPS Robot Car<h2>
      <h3> Submit your Destination coordinates</h3>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   </head>
   <body>
<form action="/get" >
....
....
    <a href="/go" >GO</a>
    <a href="/clear" >CLEAR</a>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

add two new routes listener in the code

```c
#include <Arduino.h>
  #include <WiFi.h>
  #include <AsyncTCP.h>
#include <ESPAsyncWebServer.h>
double lati1;
double logi1;
double lati2;
double logi2;
AsyncWebServer server(80);

// REPLACE WITH YOUR NETWORK CREDENTIALS
const char* ssid = "******";
const char* password = "*******";

const char* PARAM_INPUT_1 = "input1";
const char* PARAM_INPUT_2 = "input2";
const char* PARAM_INPUT_3 = "input3";
const char* PARAM_INPUT_4 = "input4";


// HTML web page to handle 3 input fields (input1, input2, input3)
const char index_html[] PROGMEM = R"rawliteral(
<!DOCTYPE HTML><html><head>
  <h2>Autonomus GPS Robot Car<h2>
  <h3> Submit your Destination coordinates</h3>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  </head><body>
  <form action="/get">
    <br> 
    Waypoint 1 Latitude : <input type="text" name="input1">
     <br>
   <br>
    Waypoint 1 Longitude: <input type="text" name="input2">
  <br><br>
    <br> 
    Waypoint 2 Latitude : <input type="text" name="input3">
     <br>
   <br>
    Waypoint 2 Longitude: <input type="text" name="input4">
  <br><br>
   <input type="submit" value="Submit">

        </form>

</body></html>)rawliteral";

void notFound(AsyncWebServerRequest *request) {
  request->send(404, "text/plain", "Not found");
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  if (WiFi.waitForConnectResult() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.println("WiFi Failed!");
    return;
  }
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("IP Address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

  // Send web page with input fields to client
  server.on("/", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request){
    request->send_P(200, "text/html", index_html);
  });

/////////  ADD IT HERE
  server.on("/go", HTTP_GET, [] (AsyncWebServerRequest *request) {
   //logic for go here
   request->redirect("/");
  });

  server.on("/clear", HTTP_GET, [] (AsyncWebServerRequest *request) {
    //logic for clear here
    request->redirect("/");
  });

  // Send a GET request to <ESP_IP>/get?input1=<inputMessage>
  server.on("/get", HTTP_GET, [] (AsyncWebServerRequest *request) {
    String latitude1;
    String latitude1Param;
    String longitude1;
    String longitude1Param;
    String latitude2;
    String latitude2Param;
    String longitude2;
    String longitude2Param;
    if (request->hasParam(PARAM_INPUT_2)||request->hasParam(PARAM_INPUT_1) ) {
    // GET input1 value on <ESP_IP>/get?input1=<latitude>

      latitude1 = request->getParam(PARAM_INPUT_1)->value();
      latitude1Param = PARAM_INPUT_1;

    // GET input2 value on <ESP_IP>/get?input2=<longitude>

       longitude1 = request->getParam(PARAM_INPUT_2)->value();
       longitude1Param = PARAM_INPUT_2;

// GET input3 value on <ESP_IP>/get?input3=<latitude>

      latitude2 = request->getParam(PARAM_INPUT_3)->value();
      latitude2Param = PARAM_INPUT_3;

    // GET input4 value on <ESP_IP>/get?input4=<longitude>

       longitude2 = request->getParam(PARAM_INPUT_4)->value();
       longitude2Param = PARAM_INPUT_4;
  }
    else {
      latitude1 = "No message sent";
      latitude1Param = "none";
      longitude1 = "No message sent";
      longitude1Param = "none";
      latitude2 = "No message sent";
      latitude2Param = "none";
      longitude2 = "No message sent";
      longitude2Param = "none";

    }
    Serial.println(latitude1);
    Serial.println(longitude1);
    Serial.println(latitude2);
    Serial.println(longitude2);
    lati1=(latitude1.toFloat());
    logi1=(longitude1.toFloat());
    lati2=(latitude2.toFloat());
    logi2=(longitude2.toFloat());
    //Serial.println(lati,6);
    //Serial.println(logi,6);
    request->send(200, "text/html", "Coordinates sent to the robot with Waypoint 1 latitude: " + latitude1 +
                                     "   longitude: " + longitude1 + "<br>" "Waypoint 2 latitude: " + latitude2 +
                                     "   longitude: " + longitude2 +"<br><a href=\"/\">Return to Home Page</a>");
  });
  server.onNotFound(notFound);
  server.begin();
}

void loop() {

}
```

Comment: it's not working, it just submits and whatever I gave in the "if command' doesn't work.

Comment: i gave  `else if(request->hasParam(PARAM_COMMIT))
  {  commitType = request->getParam(PARAM_COMMIT)->value();
    if (commitType == "Go"){
  Serial.println("YOYYYYO");
    } else if (commitType == "Clear"){
  Serial.println("fdfghgh");
    }
    }` i have changed go and clear in HTML code also

Comment: what does ```Serial.println( commitType);``` outputs ?

Comment: nothing, no output, the coordinates are still working thou

Comment: can you see the commit param in the url  once the button is clicked like this ```input1=1&input2=2&input3=3&input4=4&commit=do_thing_1```

Comment: `?commit=Go` this is what I get, ( i replaced `do thing` with go and clear)

Comment: Are you sure about using `submit` as a button type for this??

Comment: it should be working, wait i will update the answer with another approch.

Comment: i have added another solution please let me know if it works. I dont have ***esp32*** right now with be to debug the first approch. i will update once i figure it out.

Comment: where did you add  the listeners ?  i have updated the answer with their correct location.

Comment: yes,it worked there was an error, you missed an `)` and `; ` at the end of each `server.on`  in the old code

Comment: do you know how I can add some CSS to the button, to make it more appealing?

Comment: you can simply add the css directly to the head in an style tag. [example](https://jsfiddle.net/nijeesh4all/3upa9Lq4/]). **(just beware since you are storing the html  just in a string in the code itself, adding css willl make it more complex and hard to read)**

Comment: sorry for missing the semi-colon, havnt written c-code in a logn time.

Comment: yes, I made  the changes it works fine, thank you very much

Comment: @JoseBen I tried the first approach and its working for me. Also, there is a mistake in your HTML markup. ```h3``` and ```h2``` tags in HTML are not closed properly and they are only supposed to be used in body only, so you should not be using them in the ```head``` tag.

Comment: for organising your html files properly you can store them in ```PROGMEM``` and use that in your code https://github.com/me-no-dev/ESPAsyncWebServer#send-large-webpage-from-progmem-and-extra-headers

Comment: I tried it, it worked but if there is data entered on the coordinates when you click another button other than submit, the coordinates get updated. I tried placing it in `if-else loops` but no use

Comment: it was worth a try. I thing the current approach of different listeners is better than this if-else.

Comment: yes, the 2nd approach is better, thank you very much, now I have a new problem when running the whole code please look into it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60667056/task-watchdog-got-triggered-abort-was-called-at-pc-0x400de07b-on-core-0