# Task watchdog got triggered./abort() was called at PC 0x400de07b on core 0

Tags: arduino-ide, esp32, abort, watchdog

I am on an Autonomous GPS robot project. When I am running the below code after some time the esp32(devkit v1) reboots and this goes on repeating.

```
Pause for Startup... 3
Pause for Startup... 2
Pause for Startup... 1
Searching for Satellites 
Searching for Satellites 
GPS Waypoint 1 Set Waypoint #1: 0.000000 , 0.000000
Waypoint #2: 0.000000 , 0.000000
5 Satellites Acquired10.190620
76.424872
25.190620
47.424872
YOYYYYO
Go to Waypoint
E (98333) task_wdt: Task watchdog got triggered. The following tasks did not reset the watchdog in time:
E (98333) task_wdt:  - async_tcp (CPU 0/1)
E (98333) task_wdt: Tasks currently running:
E (98333) task_wdt: CPU 0: IDLE0
E (98333) task_wdt: CPU 1: async_tcp
E (98333) task_wdt: Aborting.
abort() was called at PC 0x400de07b on core 0

Backtrace: 0x4008cbf8:0x3ffbe170 0x4008ce29:0x3ffbe190 0x400de07b:0x3ffbe1b0 0x40084f01:0x3ffbe1d0 0x40148e07:0x3ffbc0d0 0x400df42b:0x3ffbc0f0 0x4008ab01:0x3ffbc110 0x4008930d:0x3ffbc130

Rebooting...
ets Jun  8 2016 00:22:57

rst:0xc (SW_CPU_RESET),boot:0x13 (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)
configsip: 0, SPIWP:0xee
clk_drv:0x00,q_drv:0x00,d_drv:0x00,cs0_drv:0x00,hd_drv:0x00,wp_drv:0x00
mode:DIO, clock div:1
load:0x3fff0018,len:4
load:0x3fff001c,len:1044
load:0x40078000,len:8896
load:0x40080400,len:5816
entry 0x400806ac
Welcome
Autonmous Mode Initiated...

IP Address: 192.168.1.18
Compass setting done
 iam here1
Pause for Startup... 
Pause for Startup... 10
Pause for Startup... 9
Pause for Startup... 8
YOYYYYO
Go to Waypoint
Pause for Startup... 7
Pause for Startup... 6
Pause for Startup... 5
Pause for Startup... 4
Pause for Startup... 3
E (10128) task_wdt: Task watchdog got triggered. The following tasks did not reset the watchdog in time:
E (10128) task_wdt:  - async_tcp (CPU 0)
E (10128) task_wdt: Tasks currently running:
E (10128) task_wdt: CPU 0: Tmr Svc
E (10128) task_wdt: CPU 1: IDLE1
E (10128) task_wdt: Aborting.
abort() was called at PC 0x400de07b on core 0

Backtrace: 0x4008cbf8:0x3ffbe170 0x4008ce29:0x3ffbe190 0x400de07b:0x3ffbe1b0 0x40084f01:0x3ffbe1d0 0x4000bfed:0x3ffbd060 0x4008a489:0x3ffbd070 0x400827d1:0x3ffbd090 0x40082843:0x3ffbd0b0 0x4008b825:0x3ffbd0d0 0x4008b924:0x3ffbd100 0x4008930d:0x3ffbd130

Rebooting...
ets Jun  8 2016 00:22:57
```

This is the msg that appears on the serial monitor. I tried debugging but can't find why this is happening.

The Code is really big, so I have uploaded only a part of it.

```
// CompaSerial Variables & Setup

HMC5883L compass;
int16_t mx, my, mz;                                                // variables to store x,y,z axis from compass (HMC5883L)
int desired_heading;                                               // initialize variable - stores value for the new desired heading
int compass_heading;                                               // initialize variable - stores value calculated from compass readings
int compass_dev = 5;                                               // the amount of deviation that is allowed in the compass heading - Adjust as Needed
                                                                   // setting this variable too low will cause the robot to continuously pivot left and right
                                                                   // setting this variable too high will cause the robot to veer off course

int Heading_A;                                                     // variable to store compass heading
int Heading_B;                                                     // variable to store compass heading in Opposite direction
int pass = 0;                                                      // variable to store which paSerial the robot is on


//*****************************************************************************************************
// GPS Locations

unsigned long Distance_To_Home;                                    // variable for storing the distance to destination

int ac =0;                                                         // GPS array counter
int wpCount = 0;                                                   // GPS waypoint counter
double Home_LATarray[2];                                          // variable for storing the destination Latitude - Only Programmed for 5 waypoint
double Home_LONarray[2];                                          // variable for storing the destination Longitude - up to 50 waypoints

int increment = 0;

//*****************************************************************************************************
// HTML Page
AsyncWebServer server(80);
const char* ssid = "******";
const char* password = "******";

const char* PARAM_INPUT_1 = "input1";
const char* PARAM_INPUT_2 = "input2";
const char* PARAM_INPUT_3 = "input3";
const char* PARAM_INPUT_4 = "input4";
const char* PARAM_COMMIT = "commit";
double lati1;
double logi1;
double lati2;
double logi2;

// HTML web page to handle 4 input fields 
const char index_html[] PROGMEM = R"rawliteral(
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
   <head>
      <h2>Autonomus GPS Robot Car<h2>
      <h3> Submit your Destination coordinates</h3>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   </head>
   <body>
   <style>

   a {
  border: 10px solid powderblue;
  padding: 10px;
  color: red;
  font-family: verdana;
  font-size: 150%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form action="/get" >
 <br> 
    Waypoint 1 Latitude : <input type="text" name="input1">
     <br>
   <br>
    Waypoint 1 Longitude: <input type="text" name="input2">
  <br><br>
    <br> 
    Waypoint 2 Latitude : <input type="text" name="input3">
     <br>
   <br>
    Waypoint 2 Longitude: <input type="text" name="input4">
  <br><br>
   <input type="submit" value="Submit">

        <br>
    <br><br>
    <br><br>


    <a href="/go" >Go to Destination</a>
    <br><br>    <br><br>
    <br><br>

    <a href="/clear" > Clear waypoints</a>
</form>
</body>
</html>)rawliteral";

void notFound(AsyncWebServerRequest *request) {
  request->send(404, "text/plain", "Not found");
}

//*****************************************************************************************************
// Extras

#define autopilot 18
 void  gesturecontroll();
 void getGPS();    
 void getCompass();  
 void Forward();
void Forward_Meter();
void Reverse();
void LeftTurn();
void RightTurn();
void SlowLeftTurn();
void SlowRightTurn();
void StopCar();
void setWaypoint();
 void move();
 void Startup();
 void goWaypoint();
 void clearWaypoints();

 int blueToothVal;  
 int flag=0;
 int button;


void setup() 
{    Serial.begin(115200);                                            // Serial 0 is for communication with the computer
     Serial.println("Welcome");

pinMode(autopilot, INPUT);

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 button = digitalRead(autopilot);
 if (button == HIGH)
 {   flag=15;
     Serial.println("Manual Control initated");
     Serial.println("ESPNow/Basic/Slave Example");
     //Set device in AP mode to begin with
     WiFi.mode(WIFI_AP);
     // configure device AP mode
     // This is the mac address of the Slave in AP Mode
     esp_wifi_set_mac(ESP_IF_WIFI_STA, &mac[0]);


     Serial.print("AP MAC: "); Serial.println(WiFi.softAPmacAddress());
     // Init ESPNow with a fallback logic
     if (esp_now_init()!=0)
      {
          Serial.println("*** ESP_Now init failed");
          while(true) {};
       }

       // Once ESPNow is successfully Init, we will register for recv CB to
      // get recv packer info.
       esp_now_register_recv_cb(OnDataRecv);
      Serial.print("Aheloiioi");                  // the remaining code for above part is not uploaded since when switch is pulled this part of code works perfectly
 }

 else{   
        S2.begin(9600, SERIAL_8N1, RXPin, TXPin);                                             // Serial 2 is for GPS communication at 9600 baud - DO NOT MODIFY - Ublox Neo 6m 
         flag=0;
        // pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);                                   // An LED indicator - Not Used
         Serial.println("Autonmous Mode Initiated...");
    WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  if (WiFi.waitForConnectResult() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.println("WiFi Failed!");
    return;
  }
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("IP Address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
      CompaSerial////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
         Wire.begin();                                                    // Join I2C bus used for the HMC5883L compass
        //compass.init();
         compass.begin();                                                 // initialize the compass (HMC5883L)
         compass.setRange(HMC5883L_RANGE_1_3GA);                          // Set measurement range  
         compass.setMeasurementMode(HMC5883L_CONTINOUS);                  // Set measurement mode  
         compass.setDataRate(HMC5883L_DATARATE_30HZ);                     // Set data rate  
         compass.setSamples(HMC5883L_SAMPLES_8);                          // Set number of samples averaged  
         compass.setOffset(0,0);
         Serial.println("Compass setting done");
               Startup(); // Run the Startup procedure on power-up one time
     }              
}  

// Main Loop

void loop()
{  button = digitalRead(autopilot);
    if (button == HIGH && flag==15)
    {      
      } 
     else
    {  Coordinates();
    getGPS();                                                        // Update the GPS location
    getCompass();                                                    // Update the CompaSerial Heading
    //Ping();                                                          // Use at your own discretion, this is not fully tested

    }    

}


void Coordinates()
{    Serial.println("i am here1");


  // Send web page with input fields to client
  server.on("/", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request){
    request->send_P(200, "text/html", index_html);
  });

  // Send a GET request to <ESP_IP>/get?input1=<inputMessage>
  server.on("/get", HTTP_GET, [] (AsyncWebServerRequest *request) {
    String latitude1;
    String latitude1Param;
    String longitude1;
    String longitude1Param;
    String latitude2;
    String latitude2Param;
    String longitude2;
    String longitude2Param;
   String commitType;;


    if (request->hasParam(PARAM_INPUT_2)||request->hasParam(PARAM_INPUT_1) ) {
    // GET input1 value on <ESP_IP>/get?input1=<latitude>

      latitude1 = request->getParam(PARAM_INPUT_1)->value();
      latitude1Param = PARAM_INPUT_1;

    // GET input2 value on <ESP_IP>/get?input2=<longitude>

       longitude1 = request->getParam(PARAM_INPUT_2)->value();
       longitude1Param = PARAM_INPUT_2;

// GET input3 value on <ESP_IP>/get?input3=<latitude>

      latitude2 = request->getParam(PARAM_INPUT_3)->value();
      latitude2Param = PARAM_INPUT_3;

    // GET input4 value on <ESP_IP>/get?input4=<longitude>

       longitude2 = request->getParam(PARAM_INPUT_4)->value();
       longitude2Param = PARAM_INPUT_4;
  }


    else {
      latitude1 = "No message sent";
      latitude1Param = "none";
      longitude1 = "No message sent";
      longitude1Param = "none";
      latitude2 = "No message sent";
      latitude2Param = "none";
      longitude2 = "No message sent";
      longitude2Param = "none";

    }


    Serial.println(latitude1);
    Serial.println(longitude1);
    Serial.println(latitude2);
    Serial.println(longitude2);
    lati1=(latitude1.toFloat());
    logi1=(longitude1.toFloat());
    lati2=(latitude2.toFloat());
    logi2=(longitude2.toFloat());
    //Serial.println(lati,6);
    //Serial.println(logi,6);
    request->send(200, "text/html", "Command succesfuly sent""<br><a href=\"/\">Return to Home Page</a>");
  });

  server.on("/go", HTTP_GET, [] (AsyncWebServerRequest *request) {
//logic for go here
Serial.println("YOYYYYO");
        goWaypoint();

request->redirect("/");
});

server.on("/clear", HTTP_GET, [] (AsyncWebServerRequest *request) {
//logic for clear here
  Serial.println("fdfghgh");
   clearWaypoints();
request->redirect("/");
});
  server.onNotFound(notFound);
  server.begin();
}

void getGPS()                                                 // Get Latest GPS coordinates
{  Serial.println("i am here2");
    while (S2.available() > 0)
    gps.encode(S2.read());
} 

// *************************************************************************************************************************************************

void setWaypoint()                                            // Set up to 5 GPS waypoints
{

//if ((wpCount >= 0) && (wpCount < 50))
if (wpCount >= 0)
  {
    Serial.print("GPS Waypoint ");
    Serial.print(wpCount + 1);
    Serial.print(" Set ");

    Home_LATarray[ac] = lati1 ;                   // store waypoint in an array   
    Home_LONarray[ac] = logi1 ;             // store waypoint in an array   
    Home_LATarray[ac] = lati2 ;               // store waypoint in an array   
    Home_LONarray[ac] = logi2 ;                  // store waypoint in an array   

    Serial.print("Waypoint #1: ");
    Serial.print(Home_LATarray[0],6);
    Serial.print(" , ");
    Serial.println(Home_LONarray[0],6);
    Serial.print("Waypoint #2: ");
    Serial.print(Home_LATarray[1],6);
    Serial.print(" , ");
    Serial.println(Home_LONarray[1],6);
    wpCount++;                                                  // increment waypoint counter
    ac++;                                                       // increment array counter

  }         
  else {Serial.print("Waypoints Full");}
}

// ************************************************************************************************************************************************* 

void clearWaypoints()
{
   memset(Home_LATarray, 0, sizeof(Home_LATarray));             // clear the array
   memset(Home_LONarray, 0, sizeof(Home_LONarray));             // clear the array
   wpCount = 0;                                                 // reset increment counter to 0
   ac = 0;

   Serial.print("GPS Waypoints Cleared");                      // display waypoints cleared

}

 // *************************************************************************************************************************************************

void getCompass()                                               // get latest compass value
 {  

  Vector norm = compass.readNormalize();

  // Calculate heading
  float heading = atan2(norm.YAxis, norm.XAxis);

  if(heading < 0)
     heading += 2 * M_PI;      
  compass_heading = (int)(heading * 180/M_PI);                   // aSerialign compass calculation to variable (compass_heading) and convert to integer to remove decimal places                                                              

 }

void Startup()
{ 
     Serial.println("Pause for Startup... ");

     for (int i=10; i >= 1; i--)                       // Count down for X seconds
      {         
        Serial.print("Pause for Startup... "); 
        Serial.println(i);
        delay(1000);                                   // Delay for X seconds
      }    


  Serial.println("Searching for Satellites "); 
  Serial.println("Searching for Satellites "); 

  while (Number_of_SATS <= 4)                         // Wait until x number of satellites are acquired before starting main loop
  {                                  
    getGPS();                                         // Update gps data
    Number_of_SATS = (int)(gps.satellites.value());   // Query Tiny GPS for the number of Satellites Acquired       
  }    
  setWaypoint();                                      // set intial waypoint to current location
  wpCount = 0;                                        // zero waypoint counter
  ac = 0;                                             // zero array counter

  Serial.print(Number_of_SATS);
  Serial.print(" Satellites Acquired");    
}   

void goWaypoint()
{   
 Serial.println("Go to Waypoint");
//Serial.print("Home_Latarray ");
//Serial.print(Home_LATarray[ac],6);
//Serial.print(" ");
//Serial.println(Home_LONarray[ac],6);   

//Serial1.print("Distance to Home");   
//Serial1.print(Distance_To_Home);

//Serial1.print("ac= ");
//Serial1.print(ac);

 while (true)  
  {                                                                // Start of Go_Home procedure 
 // bluetooth();                                                     // Run the Bluetooth procedure to see if there is any data being sent via BT
  if (blueToothVal == 5){break;}                                   // If a 'Stop' Bluetooth command is received then break from the Loop
  getCompass();                                                    // Update Compass heading                                          
  getGPS();                                                        // Tiny GPS function that retrieves GPS data - update GPS location// delay time changed from 100 to 10

  if (millis() > 5000 && gps.charsProcessed() < 10)                // If no Data from GPS within 5 seconds then send error
    Serial.println(F("No GPS data: check wiring"));     

  Distance_To_Home = TinyGPSPlus::distanceBetween(gps.location.lat(),gps.location.lng(),Home_LATarray[ac], Home_LONarray[ac]);  //Query Tiny GPS for Distance to Destination
  GPS_Course = TinyGPSPlus::courseTo(gps.location.lat(),gps.location.lng(),Home_LATarray[ac],Home_LONarray[ac]);                               //Query Tiny GPS for Course to Destination   

   /*
    if (Home_LATarray[ac] == 0) {
      Serial1.print("End of Waypoints");
      StopCar();      
      break;
      }      
   */ 
    if (Distance_To_Home == 0)                                   // If the Vehicle has reached it's Destination, then Stop
        {
        StopCar();                                               // Stop the robot after each waypoint is reached
        Serial.println("You have arrived!");                    // Print to Bluetooth device - "You have arrived"          
        ac++;                                                    // increment counter for next waypoint
        break;                                                   // Break from Go_Home procedure and send control back to the Void Loop 
                                                                 // go to next waypoint

        }   


   if ( abs(GPS_Course - compass_heading) <= 15)                  // If GPS Course and the Compass Heading are within x degrees of each other then go Forward                                                                  
                                                                  // otherwise find the shortest turn radius and turn left or right  
       {
         Forward();                                               // Go Forward
       } else 
         {                                                       
            int x = (GPS_Course - 360);                           // x = the GPS desired heading - 360
            int y = (compass_heading - (x));                      // y = the Compass heading - x
            int z = (y - 360);                                    // z = y - 360

            if ((z <= 180) && (z >= 0))                           // if z is less than 180 and not a negative value then turn left otherwise turn right
                  { SlowLeftTurn();  }
             else { SlowRightTurn(); }               
        } 


  }                                                              // End of While Loop


}
```

Comment: this might be useful. https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/issues/595#issuecomment-413829444

Comment: @NijeeshJoshy I tried it, but it doesn't work now new error  `Guru Meditation Error: Core  1 panic'ed (IntegerDivideByZero). Exception was unhandled.
Core 1 register dump:` followed by a reboot then the old error repeats

Comment: the system crashes after i click `go to destination` link in the web, and the web pages keep loading

Comment: there is some sort of division by zero happening i thing. can you post the full code?

Comment: I can send you the google drive link, is that okay? since I made the code in different tabs, copying them is a bit hard

Answer (score 1):

ESP-IDF creats a watchdog timer for idle tasks in addition to any tasks doing your work. IE, it creates two extra tasks IDLE0 & IDLE 1 (one for each core), whose sole purpose is to do nothing, ie idle. These idle tasks simply feed the watchdog whenever its respective core is idling. Whenever any task, in Arduino or in ESP-IDF, as well as interrupt routines, run with a higher priority than the IDLE tasks without delaying or blocking sufficiently long/often enough (such as when executing in a tight while loop), it triggers the watchdog, because that core is now fully busy, meaning it is no longer idling often enough, meaning the idle "tasks" get starved, so they can't reset the watchdog. Your app_main() in ESP-IDF and loop() in Arduino, run with higher priorities than the IDLE tasks. This is the source of the problem.
You either have to make some call that blocks your code for atleast 10mS in sufficient intervals, or you have to call yield() or
`vTaskDelay(NUMBER_OF_MILLISECONDS_TO_DELAY / portTICK_PERIOD_MS)`
with a minimum of 10mS (otherwise, due to discreteness, it amounts to 0, ie no delay at all, thus won't work. You can work around this by increasing the scheduler frequency).

An alternative is fully disabling the watchdog, but this nullifies its uses.
There is a more elegant solution. If you do need something to consume all available CPU time, and don't want to bother with considerations of delay or blocking, and don't want to disable the watchdog, but don't want it to bark, then put all intensive code operations in its own function or set of functions, and call it/each using the following task creation function:

`xTaskCreate(someFunction, "HumanReadableNameofTask", 4096, NULL, tskIDLE_PRIORITY, NULL);`

where your function has the following signature:

`void someFunction(void* arg)`

This won't trip the watchdog no matter what, because it uses the tskIDLE_PRIORITY priority. I'm not sure what value it has, but it seems greater than 10, because I tried 10 and it didn't work. Not sure if 11 did, which would be lower priority than the IDLE tasks. Note though, any code you place in someFunction(), won't execute at all except during times when the CPU is IDLE. So all your other code must still sleep/delay/block sufficiently enough to give it time to run. This is the ideal place for endless intensive code, such as motor control and PID control loops.

You can even do this in Arduino.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the String heap fracturing club:

```
String latitude1;
String latitude1Param;
String longitude1;
String longitude1Param;
String latitude2;
String latitude2Param;
String longitude2;
String longitude2Param;
String commitType;;
```

in combination with async webserver is a huge problem. I rewrote a ~15.000 lines application to get rid of strings (also in the used libraries) and since then no resets and reboots anymore. Hope this helps you in your project.
Use predifined fixed char arrays they will go to the stack and keep heap corruption low.Use functions like strcpy, strcat, itoa / atoi to build messages or retrieve values.
EDIT: replace String class with fixed char arrays example

```
 char numBuffer [16] ={'\0'}    // For 15 chars and the null terminator
 char latitude1 [32] ={'\0'}    // For 31 chars and the null terminator
  .... some code here ....
 strcpy (latitude1 , "No values here"); 
 //or
 strcpy (latitude1 , "Value 1: ");
 itoa (SomeIntDataNumber, numBuffer,10);
 strcat (latitude1, numBuffer)   // append the converted SomeIntDataNumber
```

One more thing if you use memset, make sure you do proper memory management, also check the used libraries for heavy use of String class. Some libs work in a static environment quite well, using them in a web context crashes the ESP. I had to ditch some libs or at least rewrite them without String class.
Further reading: https://hackingmajenkoblog.wordpress.com/2016/02/04/the-evils-of-arduino-strings/
Final Tip: Try to commenting out / replacing with dummy chars all appearancies of the String class and try the code again.

Comment: I didn't understand your solution?can you give an example?

Comment: The String class on Arduino is crap simply put - it reserved and frees memory and by doing so it punctures and fragments your heap memory. Since micro controllers have no so called garbage collection mechanism for memory recovery this leeds to crashing the board (with different often misleading failure messages). Async communication just speeds up this process because the memory gets punctured more quickly. I learned it the hard way. For an example I will EDIT my answer.

Comment: @JoseBen https://hackingmajenkoblog.wordpress.com/2016/02/04/the-evils-of-arduino-strings/

Comment: @Nijeesh Thanks for the link I forgot it almost ;-) I'll ad dit to my answer

Comment: @Codebreaker007, to be frank, I didn't understand the example well, I am a newbie to this kind of code, I didn't understand why you used strcat,itoa and numBuffer, is that all necessary?

Comment: Please read the info linked by Nijeesh and in my EDIT and learn. There is no simple solution to complex issues. Look up those functions in the documentation at e.g. arduino.cc or here on stackoverflow and learn how and why to use them. I'll only show you how to fish, you have to catch it yourself. String and float are different types - please also look up the different var types - float on micro controllers should be avoided as much as possible

Comment: @Codebreaker007, I do know those function, and did go through the link Nijeesh has provided, What I don't understand is the example, you defined two character arrays, then you gave latitude a value, then converted some int-data to string and added it to the end of latitude. The only reason I use string there is because `request->getParam(PARAM_INPUT_1)->value()` is a string value so to store it I need a string, later in the code, I convert that string into float double.I have no other use for a string there.

Comment: So at first, I didn't understand why you used strcat and all. And what is numbuffer? just a variable?

Comment: While heap fragmentation can be an issues for long running code, that's not the problem here. Look at the debug messages - the code hasn't been running for long enough to fragment the heap. And this is an ESP32, which has a lot more memory than an Arduino or ESP8266 and is less subject to heap fragmentation.

Comment: Sorry to object that,itsnot about running long, but which heap areas are affected. I made a subroutine (with a String constructor+=), when called via GET immedieatly crashed the esp32 no matter if running 1 sec or 1 hour. Just my experience with async and the crap Arduino String class. If you you write into the wrong memory section the perhaps large free heap doesn't matter. Read the linked blog

Comment: @jose bem Do you need a String (String class=or a c-style string these are two different things. If you need a c-string for your response, you just put a pointer to it. Async webserver works with c-strings, so using the String class is obsolete. Depending on the receiving format you can put any format into the c-string. numBuffer is a helper array, if using itoa and appending data, you need a buffer, because itoa like strcpy clears a char array which might be a problem creating c-strings for display.

Answer (score 0):

`wdt` is the watchdog timer. It's a timer that is used to detect whether your code has crashed. If it's not reset periodically it will throw an error and restart the ESP32. The timer needs to be reset frequently.

Notice that the error says that it was the `async_tcp` task which was running when the watchdog timer trigger. You're using the AsyncWeb server, which uses async_tcp.

When the async web server gets a page request, it calls your code. You have handlers for individual pages. Those handlers need to treat the calls to them the way we have to deal with `loop()` - if you spend 3 seconds or more without returning or calling `delay()` or `yield()`. This gives the underlying software the chance to reset the watchdog timer.

Review your web page handlers. Look for where you may spend a long time in them.

You'll find that you call `goWayPoint()` in your handler for '/go'. It has a loop in it that may block for 5 seconds. 5 seconds is too long - if that loop doesn't return or call `delay()` the watchdog timer will fire, which it does.

The easy fix is to add a call to `delay()` in the `while(true)` loop.

```
 while (true)  
  {
  delay(1);
```

this will let the underlying code reset the watchdog timer.

That won't help if other parts of your code (`getCompass()`, `getGPS()` or other things) take too long.

Ultimately you should refactor your code. You're doing too much work in the web server callbacks. That work should be done in independent tasks - perhaps in `loop()`. But that's a big project. Adding a call to `delay(1)` anywhere in a web server callback that you have a while loop or make take some time to do some processing is clumsy but should solve this problem.

Comment: adding a `delay(1)` didnt help, I finally added it in `getCompass()` and `get GPS()` also, but it doesnt work